# How do I take a good crash dump for .NET?

Tags: .net, windbg, crash-dumps, minidump

I have captured a crash dump of my 32 bit .NET application running on a 64 bit Windows operating system. During the analysis somebody found out that I have a 64 bit dump and told me that it is not possible to analyze this dump due to wrong bitness.

When using Windows Task Manager to create the dump, I was not aware that I was doing something wrong. This always worked for 32 bit operating systems.

**How can I take a good dump for .NET, especially with the correct bitness?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Why is bitness relevant here?

The bitness matters for .NET applications for the following reasons:

- a DAC (data access control) library (mscordakwks.dll) of the correct bitness is needed. There's no cross-bitness DAC available.
- the debugger needs to be able to load the SOS debugging extension of the correct bitness

It is not possible to convert a dump from 64 bit to 32 bit, although in theory it should contain all necessary information.

If you're feeling lucky, you can also try some of the instructions anyway

- [How to use Windbg to debug a dump of a 32bit .NET app running on a x64 machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/07/18/how-to-use-windbg-to-debug-a-dump-of-a-32bit-.net-app-running-on-a-x64-machine.aspx)

### How to detect the bitness of an application?

If you don't know the bitness, you can find it out like this:

Windows 7 Task Manager shows `*32` on processes:
[image: Windows 7 Task Manager]

In Windows 8 task manager, go to the `Details` tab and add a column named `Platform`:
[image: Windows 8 Task Manager]

Visual Studio shows the bitness when attaching to the process:
[image: Bitness in Visual Studio]

Process Explorer can be configured to show the `Image Type` column:
[image: Bitness in Process Explorer]

### Tools

Programs which detect bitness automatically:

- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
- [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)
- Microsoft Visual Studio
- Windows Error Reporting [LocalDumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Tools which capture a dump with specific bitness:

- 64 Bit: default Task Manager on a 64 bit OS
- 32 Bit: Task manager run from %windir%\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe on a 64 Bit OS
- 64 Bit: [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) run with the `-64` command line switch
- 32 Bit: WinDbg x86 version
- 64 Bit: WinDbg x64 version
- 32 Bit: DebugDiag x86 version
- 64 Bit: DebugDiag x64 version
- 32 Bit: ADPlus x86 version
- 64 Bit: ADPlus x64 version

Just choose the bitness according to your application, not according the OS.

### Why is memory relevant here?

For .NET you need a full memory dump, otherwise you cannot figure out the content of the objects. To include full memory, do the following:

- in WinDbg, specify `/ma` when doing `.dump`
- in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), choose "Create full dump" (although technically, the result is still a minidump)
- in [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) , apply the `-ma` command line switch
- in Visual Studio, choose "Minidump with heap"
- Task Manager will always create a dump with full memory
- For Windows Error Reporting [LocalDumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) set `DumpType` to `2`

### Visual Studio instructions

I found out that many developers aren't even aware that Visual Studio can create dumps. The reason probably is that the menu is invisible for a long time. These are the steps:

- Start Visual Studio: menu is invisible
- Attach to a process: menu is still invisible
- Break: menu becomes visible (find it under Debug / Save dump as)

### Why 64 bit dumps of 32 bit applications at all?

Probably just for debugging the WoW64 layer itself.

Comment: Perhaps add how you are able to determine whether the process is 32 or 64 bit - for example in win8 Task Manager you need to show the `Platform` column to determine this. Also in your title `How to take a good...` perhaps consider using the word 'correct' instead of the word good

Comment: I've been using VS for as long as it has existed and I somehow overlooked the VS save dump command!