# Windows Crash Dump call stack only shows wow64

Tags: windows, windbg, coredump, crash-dumps

### Problem

I have a Windows application that we developed for in house use. Thanks to Windows Error Handling, the window stays open and I can easily generate a crash dump from the task manager.

I have used crash-dumps on linux through eclipse once before, but this is the first time on Windows.

### Hardware

The server is Windows 2012, and my development machine is Windows 7.

### Windbg

When I load the crash dump in Windbg, load my symbols, then choose to look at the call stack, the only listings are:

[image]

How can I see my application call stack specifically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your applications is a 32Bit application and you used the 64Bit Taskmgr to generate a dump.

You should use [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) instead, [it cares about the bitness](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sysinternals/archive/2013/02/04/updates-pendmoves-v1-2-process-explorer-v15-3-sigcheck-v1-91-zoomit-v4-42.aspx):

> Process Explorer v15.3:  It also creates dump files that match the
>   bitness of the target process

Or run the 32Bit Taskmgr from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` to generate the dump.

Comment: So Simple, its brilliant!  I didn't even consider that the TaskMgr was 64Bit when i launched it from the command line. This is also not the first time that the 64 bit version has bit me when I needed the 32 bit version (im looking at you ODBC)

Comment: ok, if it fixed your issue, accept it to "close" the question

Comment: I'll gladly accept if it works (which i expect it will).  please allow me to confirm when i get back to office on monday (since this is weekend)

Comment: I left the application hanging over the weekend, so i was able to generate the 32bit version first thing this morning. I ended up using the 32bit version of Taskmgr instead of the ProcessExplorer. Worked perfectly.

Comment: btw, you can also force WER to generate crash dumps automatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

As [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890003/480982), you have taken a 64 bit dump of a 32 bit application. There are [multiple options to take a 32 bit dump of a 32 bit application on 64 bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-correct-bitness-crash-dump-for-net), just choose the one which is most comfortable to you.

**Update**: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76477081/480982) describes how to use soswow64 to fix the bitness issue.

If this is the only dump you have and there's hardly a chance to get a better dump, you can try `!sw` to switch to 32 bit mode:

```
0:014> !sw
Switched to 32bit mode
0:014:x86>
```

Note how the command prompt changed. IMHO the exact same effect can be achieved by `.effmach`

```
0:014> .effmach x86
Effective machine: x86 compatible (x86)
0:014:x86>
```

except that you specify the mode explicitly where the `!sw` command toggles between the two.

In case of a .NET application, none of these ever helped me, since SOS cannot work with dumps of incorrect bitness.

Comment: +1 Thats a great tip! I wish I could have accepted both answers, but in the end I went with @magicandre1981 since switching the mode (in my case) did not seem to result in a full call stack (although I may have done something wrong).