# Can't start program from task scheduler

Tags: c#, task

I was create program auto fetching database.

I was start application, it run success.

But in create task scheduler to run program daily.

It was error:`0x41303: Task has not yet run.`.

[This error in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEXsq.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure Windows Error Reporting to create [local dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See also [How to take a good crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24874028/4136325).
2. Reproduce the crash
3. Open the dump in Visual Studio
4. Press the "Play" button to start debugging

That should show you the exception and the source code where it happens.