# Examining a managed exception in an unmanaged thread

Tags: c#, c++, exception, windbg, crash-dumps

I'm looking into a mini-dump file where the main thread (c++) utilized CLR to launch a managed (C#.NET) window, an exception was thrown in the managed portion, and crashed the application. I've been searching around looking at techniques to examine an exception details for clues, however they're mainly for one or the other (an entirely unmanaged stack & thread or an entirely managed stack & thread).

The portion of the managed callstack is below, where I can see an exception was raised inside the .NET portion, but I'm not really sure of a method to digging into viewing the details of what was raised. I'm still fairly new at digging through a .dmp file, so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
001ddb04 68b92a42 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
001ddba8 68c655ef clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x276
001ddbd8 68c6de52 clr!UnwindAndContinueRethrowHelperAfterCatch+0x83
001ddc6c 627528df clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0x59b
001ddc7c 62778872 clrjit!Compiler::impResolveToken+0x3a
001de3ac 62751d53 clrjit!Compiler::impImportBlockCode+0x29b3
001de42c 62751f48 clrjit!Compiler::impImportBlock+0x5f
001de444 62753405 clrjit!Compiler::impImport+0x235
001de464 62753635 clrjit!Compiler::compCompile+0x63
001de4a0 62753823 clrjit!Compiler::compCompileHelper+0x2fa
001de518 627536f6 clrjit!Compiler::compCompile+0x213
001de608 6275385f clrjit!jitNativeCode+0x1e3
001de62c 68a74710 clrjit!CILJit::compileMethod+0x25
001de67c 68a747a9 clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x41
001de6bc 68a747eb clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x31
001de720 68a73684 clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x2a
001deab8 68a73920 clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x3ca
001deb94 68a81e5e clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x36b
001dec08 68a550b6 clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0x59d
001dec70 68a44279 clr!PreStubWorker+0xed
001deca0 16c5185a clr!ThePreStub+0x16
001deda4 5ae8f887 0x16c5185a
001dedc0 5ae20c9c MYDLL!CLoader::InvokeCSharpControl
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0x16c5185a` is an address in memory where the .NET code has been compiled by the JIT compiler. Due to the just-in-time compilation, there's no symbol like in C++ and you need different tools (extensions for WinDbg).

First, check if it's a .NET exception with `.exr -1`. Except for a few exceptions, the code should be `0xE0434F4D` (`.COM` in ASCII characters).

If that's the case, load the SOS extension to analyze the .NET details: `.loadby sos clr`. Next, run the command `!PrintException` (`!pe` in short) to get details about the exception and `!ClrStack` (casing is not relevant) to get details about the .NET call stack.

There may be more details available if you [have a good crash dump for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net).

Comment: Thanks for the details. It looks like this is not a .NET exception - instead an exception code representing STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION.