# Error while debugging an exe (client) with windbg

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, packet

```
ModLoad: 6ff20000 70001000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
ModLoad: 76a40000 76adc000   C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
(4c34.25fc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00e24000 ebx=00000000 ecx=76f12780 edx=76f12780 esi=76f12780 edi=76f12780
eip=76ed6af0 esp=0a41f774 ebp=0a41f7a0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
76ed6af0 cc              int     3
```

So this is the error i am getting while debugging an executable (client) with windbg.

First of all the program i want to use is a "packet-sender" for an old game well there are more little features than that but i am mostly using the "packet-sender". To tell you guys some context the game got updated some months ago and previously i could easily send packets and recv packets but now after their executable got updated it won't work anymore -> send/recv packets crashes the game completly. I tried to change some stuff with dnspy related to the sendfunction in the "packet-sender" but nothing ever worked so i tried to debug that one now and that is were i am now.

I am really not sure why it won't work with the new executable (client) but still works with the old one.

```
(ee0.2aec): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(ee0.2aec): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(ee0.2aec): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
ModLoad: 08220000 08270000   image08220000
ModLoad: 0a210000 0a260000   image0a210000
ModLoad: 08220000 08270000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\2.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll
ModLoad: 08220000 08270000   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\2.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll
(ee0.3f9c): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
```

This one is after sending the packet to the old executable (client) while debugging there are no real errors and the game also does not crash at all the packets are sent perfectly the problem here is just i wouldn't be able to connect to the login server but i don't care about that just want to update the "packet-sender" if that is possible without having the source code.

I hope i didn't forget something but i think that those things were the most important ones and i am sorry if i couldn't explain it that well but that's just how bad my english is i guess. And also if there is a need for some codes to understand the whole problem even better i can send it if that is even allowed. Tbh i am not even sure if that is the correct website to ask that question but i hope so.

Comment: First chance errors are quite common (and handled in most cases without crashing the process). I suggest you capture crash dumps and debug them instead of live debugging (since you don't know much about live debugging yet).

Comment: Which error do you get? `Break instruction exception` or `CLR exception` or both? Which one do you want to analyze? CLR exceptions are .NET exceptions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999823/examining-a-managed-exception-in-an-unmanaged-thread on how to further inspect those.

Comment: I also agree with @LexLi: you should analyze second-chance exceptions, not first chance exceptions. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net and set up WER LocalDumps to capture the real crash. Having a crash dump makes it easier for us to help you, since the data will always remain the same, while in live debugging, it may change over time