# Windbg command clrstack not working

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg

I need to do crash dump analysis for a .net exe using Windbg.
I read multiple blogs on MSDN to setup my Windbg but looks  like it still has issues loading 'mscordacwks.dll'.
Upon running this command i get this:

> Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005 Verify that 1) you have a
>   recent build of the debugger (6.2.14 or newer)
>               2) the file mscordacwks.dll that matches your version of mscorwks.dll is 
>                   in the version directory
>               3) or, if you are debugging a dump file, verify that the file 
>                   mscordacwks_.dll is on your symbol path.
>               4) you are debugging on the same architecture as the dump file.
>                   For example, an IA64 dump file must be debugged on an IA64
>                   machine.
>
> You can also run the debugger command .cordll to control the
>   debugger's load of mscordacwks.dll.  .cordll -ve -u -l will do a
>   verbose reload. If that succeeds, the SOS command should work on
>   retry.
>
> If you are debugging a minidump, you need to make sure that your
>   executable path is pointing to mscorwks.dll as well.

Here are quick details of my environment:

> 1. EXE is 32 -bit so using x86 debugger
> 2. In the following path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 the two DLLs are located
>      :
>      ->mscorwks.dll
>      ->mscordacwks.dll file version: 2.0.50727.5485
> 3. Symbol path is : c:\debug\symbols
> 4. Debugging tools(i.e. Windbg installation) is located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86
> 5. Copied mscorwks.dll and mscordacwks.dll in this path and renamed to(as per some blog on MSDN) :
>      -> mscordacwks_x86_x86_2.0.50727.5485
>      -> mscorwks_x86_x86_2.0.50727.5485

Not sure if these names are correct or not.

Still it never worked.

Comment: What dump type do you have (64 bit or 32 bit)? Note that there's no mixed architecture DLL (64 bit dump but 32 bit executable). See also [How to take a good crash dump for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net). FYI: I wrote [a tool](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/download-mscordacwks-collector/) that does the collection and renaming for you. I also provide many [of those DLLs](http://sos.debugging.wellisolutions.de/) for download (in case you need one which you don't have present).

Comment: If the command `lm m wow64` results in addresses, you have the wrong type of dump.