# Is there a Windows alternative for UNIX crash core-files

Tags: windows, unix, crash-dumps, core-file

I've asked this question on the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1124986/is-there-a-windows-alternative-for-unix-crash-core-files/1124992#1124992) forum, but there I was redirected here, can anybody help me?

Hereby a copy of my question:

I am facing a crash on a Windows system at customer premises. I had such situations regularly in the past when I was working for customers with UNIX computers. In that case, I only needed to investigate the core files and I knew about where the crash has happened.

Does such a system exist for Windows environment, and in case yes, how does it work and on which Windows systems is it supported? (I've been looking on the internet but the only dumps (cores) I've found where the ones where the whole Windows system crashes, not just a program)

Comment: Yes, the proper word to google is "minidump".

Comment: Minidumps aren't written automatically by applications upon crashing. You'll either have to set up an unhandled exception filter and call [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx), or set up [Windows Error Reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513641.aspx) to [collect user-mode dumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181.aspx) (Server 2008/Vista SP1 and above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of a core dump on Windows is a minidump. It has the `.dmp` file extension and can e.g. be opened in Visual Studio or in WinDbg.

There are many ways of getting such a crash dump. I once answered [How do I take a good crash dump for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net), but most of that can also be applied to C++ and VB6.

Java has it's own way of reporting crashes and interpreted languages like Python, too.