# Can DebugDiag cause exceptions to stop being thrown or prevent general .net exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, debugdiag

I know this question sounds nuts but here is my scenario.  I have three Windows Server 2012 R2 web servers behind a load balancer and all three are weighted the same (33%).  All three servers are running our ASP.NET site on IIS.  These servers are identical in every way.  Every 2-3 days each server has been throwing an unhandled exception which kills the worker process.  Over a week ago I created a crash rule in DebugDiag for our application on "Server A".  Servers B & C continue to throw the exception but server A has not thrown the exception since we created the DebugDiag rule.  I have verified that all three servers are getting the same amount of requests from our load balancer.  Here is the exception we are getting:

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18202, time stamp: 0x569e7eb1
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352

Does anyone have any insight as to why DebugDiag seems to 'solve' the problem for us or how we can debug this?

Comment: use it on the other two servers, lol, problem solved

Comment: lol!  I did joke around with the team about doing that.

Comment: Yes, it can. Indeed it attaches a debugger to your process and it might slightly and rarely change the way the code runs.

Comment: @LexLi - Any thoughts on how to debug without impacting the way the code runs?

Comment: @Bloodhound try to use Windows Error Reporting to collect dumps.

Comment: To me it seems you're getting that information out of the Windows event log. With DebugDiag attached, DebugDiag handles the exception and writes its own log file / crash report. Once it's handled it might happen that DebugDiag simply exits the process instead of letting it crash. Therefore you don't have events in Windows Event viewer. Have you looked into the DebugDiag results?

Comment: Related: there are many other ways of creating crash dumps for analysis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net, especially look into WER LocalDumps.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - Yes I looked at the dumps and the file is empty.  I'll check out that other question you mentioned.