# Debugging displaying different results as to when im running Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Good day fellow coders

I've experienced a situation where i was responsible for developing a module/section in an existing system. When i ran my visual studio everything works perfectly (saving to the database and editing information from the database). When i gave my project manager the debug folder to test, it just bombed but when i run visual studio it works.

Can anyone please assist me because i'm looking like an idiot

Thank you

Comment: There could be a 1,000 reasons for why this is happening. When you post a question, you have to provide as much code and information as possible so people here can help you. You have provided none. I suggest you edit your question adding your code, exception messages, environment settings etc.

Comment: When running the debug an error message pops up "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Meaning information from the database doesn't return. This error only occurs when running the debug in the bin folder. When i actually run the application through visual studio it then returns the information.

Comment: Bomb = preventing the program from executing any further

Comment: This is no terror attack haha

Comment: What kind of project is this? What is your database?

Comment: @Drizzybass `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Meaning information from the database doesn't return.` Don't make assumptions, and always check if you actually get anything from the db. instead of just doing stuff with it

Comment: It is a visual studio 2012 wpf application. I can get information from the database but only when visual studio is actually running. So the database is fine and loaded with information.

Comment: Show us the code that is 'bombing'.

Comment: @Drizzybass, How did you give your  project manager the debug folder to test? Do you mean that you change the VS machine or others? Not really run your app, please enable the Exception settings in your VS:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw(v=vs.110).aspx, and then debug your app using the VS IDE, how about the result?

Answer (score 0):

Write an installer that installs all the dependencies and does all the necessary configuration. Ship that to your manager instead of a debug folder. 
I can recommend [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

If it still bombs, [take a crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net) and analyze it. It will give you an exception name and a line of code which is responsible.