# When the window of the program is not responding, how to find which Message Procedure is blocking in the Message Loop?

Tags: windows, winapi, windbg, ollydbg, win32-process

For example, if a release program appears no responding in Windows, what tools and methods should be used to find out which message procedure caused the long time no return?

Comment: Create a mini dump and look at the stack trace on the main thread

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why create the mini dump? The program does not crash, it's just not responding for a while or  ever.

Comment: The mini dump will capture the state of the hung program so you can study it. The program will resume running after the dump is captured. It's like taking a picture of an athlete to see what's wrong with their swing.

Comment: and windbg  can do a better job with !analyze -hang instead of the standard !analyze  -v if you have a hung dump

Comment: It's not responding, usually, because it is busy doing something else. This will tell you what that something else is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan   How to generate the mini dump of UI thread context,  outside of the process condition?  The program is release version. Thanks.

Comment: Ask a websearch engine

Comment: Related: [How do I take a good crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net)

Comment: Suggestion: just to be sure, take several crash dumps and check if the call stack is always the same. Otherwise you might be unlucky by taking tha crash dump exactly that millisecond which is not responsible for the hang.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan，Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, Thank you

Comment: Can also consider using ProcessExplorer to view the thread stack, if dump analysis might be too intimidating. You'd need to make sure to have symbols setup first.

Comment: @kvr, Thanks. Excuse me,  where to  find the thread stack in  ProcessExplorer? I have not found it.

Comment: @cmf41013 see this https://superuser.com/questions/462989/how-can-i-view-the-call-stack-of-a-running-process-thread