# I have a deadlock between 2 threads, and I am really not sure why there's a deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, deadlock, .net-4.8

All,

Software/Tech: Winforms application on .net framework 4.8

**Build Configuration: Debug Build**

Synchronization construct used where deadlock occurs: Monitor using a privately scoped object to the class

Deadlock: Worker thread (Thread #2) deadlocks with UI thread

See below the code that dead locks and please read the comments that explain the flow and where the deadlock occurs and why I am puzzled why it occurs.

**UPDATE: I am aware this a real poor design and I will fix it and I over simplified the example to make it clearer where the dead lock occurs. The point of this post is to figure out why the lock is not released causing a dead lock.**

**UPDATE 2: Moral of the story: Don't mix sync with async. RIP**

Code:

```
public class Form
{
    private static SomeSharedObject sharedObj = new SomeSharedObject();
    
    Init() // callled once
    {
        // UI thread starts initialization
        
        // register for notifications (later Thread #2, background worker thread, will callback Device_Attach causing a dead lock between itself and UI thread)
        sharedObj.Attach += new EventHandler<USBConnectionEventArgs>(Device_Attach);
        
        
        // kick off background worker task
        bw.RunWorkerAsync() // UI thread spawns the 2nd thread (Thread #2) that will dead lock with the UI thread
        // UI thread continues to run ...
        
        // UI thread calls a method on a shared static instance (between UI thread and Thread #2) to access some property
        var devices = sharedObj.ConnectedDevices; // DEAD LOCKS! See pseudo implementation of SomeSharedObject
    }
    
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        sharedObj.ReadState(); // Thread #2 reading the state
    }
    
    void Device_Attach(object sender, USBConnectionEventArgs e)
    {
        _RefreshHwDeviceList(); // Still Thread #2, but now refereshing the UI
    }
    
    delegate void RefreshHwDeviceListCallBack();
    private void _RefreshHwDeviceList()
    {
        // Thread #2 enters here to update the UI
        // Since we're here on background worker thread and need to update UI, switch to UI thread.
        // NOTE: Bam, we're in a dead lock (at line HwDeviceList.Invoke())! UI thread is still blocked in SomeSharedObject.ConnectedDevices (on the _accessLock), but
        // that doesn't make sense since Thread #2 released the _accessLock before calling Attach callback (why is this lock still held by Thread #2)
        // How do I know?
        //  When I break in VS and open threads watch window, VS clearly says that the main UI thread is blocked on Thread #2 at the location
        // of the _accessLock in SomeSharedObject.ConnectedDevices property.
        if (HwDeviceList.InvokeRequired) 
        {
            var callback = new RefreshHwDeviceListCallBack(_RefreshHwDeviceList);
            HwDeviceList.Invoke(callback, new object[] { });
        }
        else
        {
            // update UI on UI thread
        }
    }
}

public class SomeSharedObject
{
    private readonly object _accessLock = new object();
    public event EventHandler<USBConnectionEventArgs> Attach;
    
    public IEnumerable<IDevice> ConnectedDevices
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_accessLock) // NOTE: This line is where the UI thread will wait indefinetly wait for Thread #2, but Thread #2 should of released this lock (see ReadState())!
            {
                
                return _deviceList
                    .Where(x => x.IsConnected ||
                            ((x as IUSBDevice)?.IsAttached ?? false))
                    .ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void ReadState()
    {
        var attachingDevice = e.Device;
        lock (_accessLock) // Thread #2 grabs the lock first, so UI thread is blocked, okay that's fine as long as at the end of its scope the lock is released
        {
            // read some state
        } //NOTE: release the lock here before raising the event below so we don't DEAD lock the UI thread (but the lock is not released, why????)
        
        // Thread #2 now calls back to the Form's handler
        if (Attach != null)
        {
            Attach(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set those locks hoping that the UI Thread would access a list of devices when this list is ready to be consumed? IMO, you have everything backwards. Use an event to notify the UI Thread when the list is ready, so it's actually ready and the two Threads don't clash with each other. Ditch the BackGroundWorker and use an `IProgress<T>` delegate (create it in the UI Thread and pass it to the worker method, it can also raise an event) to notify the UI Thread of the progress. No invocations (using the wrong object, BTW) required

Comment: I will redesign the whole thing, it is poor at best. Locks were only in place so that the shared state in SomeSharedObject is protected. Yes, there's a possibility that the UI thread might get a lock first and find there are no devices connected. But that's not the point, I want to know why is the lock not released by Thread #2 just before calling the Attach() delegate. It annoys me not knowing this and messes up with my understanding of the Monitor class.

Comment: Pet peeve:  _deadlock_, a computing term where competing actions are waiting for each other to release a resource, is **one word**.  A "dead lock", would be a lock that has jammed or reached the end of its lifespan, or maybe an electrical lock with a dead battery.

Comment: @ActiveX do you have a [mre] which you can post somewhere? Like github?

Comment: Also just for lolz can you try adding `Thread.Sleep(500)` after the lock in `ReadState`?

Comment: @GuruStron Unfortunately no, I am really tempted to do it but I am afraid when I create a simple example of this scenario it might just work because the timing might be different to lesser amount of code running

Comment: @GuruStron I added sleep, no difference, even tried 3.5 secs pause. I don't think it is related to timing per say. Somethings else is going on. Btw this a debug build, optimizations are off.

Comment: @ActiveX does the behaviour persist in Release build?

Comment: Deadlocks are really easy to analyze: you have all the time of the world. Create a crash dump file (DMP file). You say "I don't think it is related to timing", but timing is one of the 4 preconditions for a deadlock, i.e. timing is involved in every deadlock.

Comment: @GuruStron Happens in release build also.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I guess it came out wrong. Yes, deadlocks are a lot about timing. I meant to say in regards to Sleep() suggestion, that this probably will not change the outcome ... I don't think there's a bug in Monitor? What is a DMP file? How is that going help find out the root cause? Please elaborate.

Comment: A BackGroundWorker is not a Thread, it's an [AsyncOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation), coupled with the SynchronizationContext that started it. Synchronous invokations / locking are not its friends. You cannot solve evident race conditions (even though the code is incomplete) using locks here (and synchronous invokations). Probably the lock does wait but doesn't pulse as intended. Use the appropriate tools for the task at hand -- BTW, I have no idea why a BGW is used here, you're doing nothing I can see that the BGW is designed for

Comment: There are many ways of taking a crash dump: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24874028/480982

Comment: @Jimi I see. BGW still uses a pool thread to accomplish its task, so it still a schedulable Windows Thread albeit with SynchronizationContext machinery. I still find it illogical, that the dead lock would occur in this scenario (Even though it uses SynchronizationContext in the background). That design of api buffles me. Also, don't worry about BGW why, where (I already said, it is oversimplified example and I took out code that actually makes sense. Also, this deadlock allowed me to spot a mistake I made that I will remove after I get clear answers to this problem, for education purpose).

Comment: You get that behavior while debugging? Then simply stop execution when you think you are in that deadlock situation and take a look at the parallel stacks window in Visual Studio where every thread currently is and see if  you find one beeing inside a lock block that you did not expect.

Comment: @Ralf Yes, during debugging (and release build, no debug). I verified with Parallel stacks, stacks look good as described in this post. I wonder, curious, if the fact that I am using Control.Invoke() to return to UI thread has do with the dead lock. In other words, more behind the scene machinery is involved as hinted by Jimi. Let me try to comment that line of code out and see what happens.

Comment: Okay tried it, commenting out the Control.Invoke(), dead lock is gone. I guess maybe that was obvious lol

Comment: Yes, the delegates are enqueued (`QueueUserWorkItem()`), the AsynchOperation (the asynch delegate) is started asynchronously (`[Delegate].BeginInvoke()`). Acknowledging what blocks what / causes a collision is not that simple just eyeballing it, but you cannot exclude something is going to run amok (quite literally here). If you add synchronous invokations in the mix, when you cannot test the state of the affected Thread (`InvokeRequired`, given its nature, doesn't help at all here), well, you just tested it... Don't mess with the SynchronizationContext, it messes back

Comment: Thanks Jimi. For such great explanation I will demystify for you why I am using BGW: When the application starts it loads in parallel various parts, one of these is enumerating attached USB devices and I wanted to run this in parallel (using BGW) because of the hardware latency. This code was written pre-async days (yeap .net 2.0). BGW is fine, just my stupid code that I placed recently is in the wrong place. Since it depends on the USB hardware being initialized, it should run after BGW finishes device discovery, not in parallel while hardware is being discovered.

Comment: Also, I have mixed feeling no how MS implemented certain parts of async/await because sometimes you have to mix the two paradigms (interop between sync/async libraries). It feels like  you have to walk on glass when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all responses, answer is in the comments.
TLDR; When mixing sync with async, you cannot look at the problem from just executing threads point of view, you have take into account the entire async infrastructure into consideration (ex Synchronization context and its machinery).
Basically, avoid mixing async with sync code.